# JMeter testing on GRPC Server: Server-side exception: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter, grpc, http2

I have got this issue with JMeter when conducting response time tests on the GRPC API which is a spring boot server. I have read in similar cases that it has something to do with TLS config, but I'm not sure about that in my case. I only have this issue when testing about 1000 requests in 30 seconds and then about 950 are ok 200 and 50 throw this server-side exception.

```
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 16030100890100008503038bc456665bba06cf1a9f93f4f4
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:103) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.readClientPrefaceString(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:306) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:239) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:438) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.31.1.jar!/:1.31.1]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bytes `160301` are the first TLS bytes sent by a client to a server.

In your case, the server replied that it was expecting an HTTP/2 client preface.

This means that your client is trying to send encrypted bytes to a clear-text server port.

Check that you are using the right scheme, which must be `http`, not `https` (as the server expect clear-text bytes).

Or, configure your server to accept encrypted bytes on that port.